# Read Cross-Domain (Cross-Sub-Domain) Cookies in ColdFusion (HTTPS)

Tags: cookies, coldfusion, cross-domain, subdomain

I need to read a cookie created on https://sub1.domain.com from http://origin.domain.com using ColdFusion. I've seen a lot of info about how to create a cookie in a subdomain using CFCOOKIE, but I don't know how to access a cookie that already exists.

Will the HTTPS make this impossible anyway?

ADDENDUM:
The checked answer below correctly addresses the question as worded above. In my case, it did not work. I should have explained: The cookie on sub1.domain.com is created by a hosted third party product - not written in coldfusion and not under my control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is really quite easy. When you create the cookie, give it a domain attribute equal to your domain. The important part to remember is that it MUST have a leading dot.

```
<cfcookie name="mycookie" value="myvalue" domain=".mydomain.com" path="/" />
```

The leading dot tells the browser to send the cookie to any subdomain of mydomain.com which would include sub.mydomain.com and blah.mydomain.com.

You would then be able to access the cookie from any of the subdomains just as you would any other cookie:

```
<cfset thevalue = cookie.mycookie />
```

You should do this as a best practice to support older browsers.

Here is the statement from RFC2109: HTTP State Management Mechanisms that could affect older browsers

> "To prevent possible security or privacy violations, a user agent
>   rejects a cookie (shall not store its information) if… The value for
>   the Domain attribute contains no embedded dots or does not start with
>   a dot."

I believe this is overridden by RFC 2965: HTTP State Management Mechanism which states

> "Domain=value OPTIONAL.  The value of the Domain attribute specifies
>   the domain for which the cookie is valid.  If an explicitly specified
>   value does not start with a dot, the user agent supplies a leading
>   dot."

Which explains why it might be working for you in, presumably, a modern browser. I would still suggest you add it.

Comment: Actually, I just tried this out - the leading dot wasn't necessary when I did it.

Comment: HTTPS can ready HTTP cookie, but not the other way around, right?

Comment: The tests I just tried worked both ways.  Presumably if you want to limit it to just https, you can specify secure="true"

Comment: The leading dot may not be necessary for all browsers, but it could be for some. It is a best practice to include it. It is up to the user agent (the browser) to determine if the lack of a leading dot means that it should include subdomains or not, so it is in your best interest to explicitly define the behavior by including it.

Comment: @Henry Cookies work fine between HTTP and HTTPS, unless, as jake said, the secure attribute is set. That only tells the browser not to send the cookie over an non-TLS/SSL connection. Otherwise cookies are sent based on their domain and path setting.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough reply. The comments were great, too. Unfortunately, I left out a key detail. I don't have control of the app that creates the cookie on sub1.domain.com It's a third party, non-CF SaaS (Blackboard).

Comment: Then you are out of luck if the other app does not create domain cookies. You may need to look at having your app make a cfhttp call to the other domain and pulling the cookies out of the response.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I'm giving you the check anyway since you answered the question as originally phrased. Thanks.

Comment: @Jason Dean I have the same problem.Do i need to set <cfapplication name="mydog" setclientcookies="No"/> or just <cfcookie name="mycookie" value="myvalue" domain=".mydomain.com" path="/" /> is enough?

Comment: Only use setClientCookies="no" if you are planning to set the session token cookies (CFID/CFToken) yourself. It has nothing to do with other cookies that you create.